# How to show raster's cell value over its map in levelplot?

Tags: raster, r, levelplot

Hy, Is there any way to plot each cell of raster with its values in level plot ?
Raster is attched here(
[image: raster])

I have tried these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569666/showing-data-values-on-levelplot-in-r, but it is only ploting the matrix values.

If anybody can help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it.
First I convert the raster into points in ArcMap using *raster to point* and overlay it over the levelplot by adding a layer as

```
levelplot(raster)+
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.text(coordinates(vector_layer), 
   txt = vector_corelation_$grid_code)) #adding the row having values to show on raster
```

[image]